# Python function to count 7's

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

I think I'm almost there on this function I'm trying to write, but just can't get the last piece. I have to write a function that will return "True" if the number 7 appears in a string exactly 3 times, and "False" if it's more or less. I can't figure out how to get it so it'll search for non-consecutive 7's. Any hints?

```
def luckySevens(aStr):
    if "777" in aStr:
        return True
    else:
        return False


#You can use these lines to test your code. They are not used
#for grading, so feel free to change them.

testStringTrue = "happy777bday"
print(testStringTrue, luckySevens(testStringTrue))
testStringFalse1 = "happy77bday"
print(testStringFalse1, luckySevens(testStringFalse1))
testStringFalse2 = "h777app7y77bday"
print(testStringFalse2, luckySevens(testStringFalse2))
```

Comment: What restrictions does the assignment impose? If there aren't any, `return aStr.count('7') == 3` can be the whole body of your function.

Comment: I don't think there are any as long as it uses a function. It's a pretty introductory level course but I can give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please link me to the duplicate of this question? I couldn't find anything similar to it.

Comment: Reload the page, the link to the duplicate is in a giant banner above the body of your question.